# Android app made with beeware : How can I change the default beeware icon with my own?

Tags: beeware

I can not change default beeware icon in my app made with beeware

beeware icon always shown when I run my app on my android device

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to change the application icon of an app in beeware, python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64119895/how-to-change-the-application-icon-of-an-app-in-beeware-python)

Answer (score 0):

Here how you can replace the beeware logo in android app:  go to `\your_app_name\build\your_app_name\android\gradle\app\src\main\res`

in the res folder replace both pictures `ic_launcher.png` and `ic_launcher_round.png` in each one of the subfolders below with `your_own_logo.png` redrawn at various resolutions as shown (and stated in `\your_app_name\build\your_app_name\android\gradle\briefcase.toml`)

In each resolution subfolder rename `your_own_logo.png` picture as `ic_launcher.png` and `ic_launcher_round.png`.
The subfolders are

```
mipmap-mdpi (48x48 pixels)
mipmap-hdpi (72x72 pixels)
mipmap-xdpi (96x96 pixels)
mipmap-xxdpi(144x144 pixels)
mipmap-xxxdpi(192x192 pixels)
```

This will replace the app logo